# How to replace specific sub-string of a string using python while we have multiple sub-string?

Tags: python, string, replace, substring

I have a sentence suppose

```
s = 'alpha-catenin inhibits beta-catenin signaling by preventing formation of a beta-catenin*T-cell factor*DNA complex.'
```

Now, I want to replace first occurred **'beta-catenin'** by **'PROTEIN'** while the second occurred beta-catenin should not be replaced i.e. the desired output should be

```
rep_s = s = 'alpha-catenin inhibits PROTEIN signaling by preventing formation of a beta-catenin*T-cell factor*DNA complex.'
```

Also, I have the index value and length of first occurred beta-catenin i.e. **'offset' = 23** and **'length' = 12**.

I have tried a code

```
s1.replace(s1[23:(23+12)], 'PROTEIN')
```

But the output comes

```
'alpha-catenin inhibits PROTEIN signaling by preventing formation of a PROTEIN*T-cell factor*DNA complex.'
```

It simply replaces all two *beta-catenin* which is not desirable. Please help me to get my desired output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first one to be replaced, you can use the `count` optional param in `replace()`. This won't work if you want to replace nth occurance when n != 1

```
s.replace('beta-catenin', 'PROTEIN', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace` replaces every occurrence of the given substring. It doesn't know you've passed it a slice; it just receives the string `'beta-catenin'` as something to find and replace.

But since you've already found the indexes you want to cut at, you can do this just with slices:

```
result = s1[:23] + 'PROTEIN' + s1[23+12:]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can archive this by the following 2 way

Way1: Use string replace function to replace 1st occurrence

```
s = 'alpha-catenin inhibits beta-catenin signaling by preventing formation of a beta-catenin*T-cell factor*DNA complex.'
s.replace("beta-catenin", "PROTEIN", 1)
print(s)
```

output:

```
alpha-catenin inhibits PROTEIN signaling by preventing formation of a beta-catenin*T-cell factor*DNA complex.
```

way 2: use python's regex

```
import re
s = 'alpha-catenin inhibits beta-catenin signaling by preventing formation of a beta-catenin*T-cell factor*DNA complex.'
s = re.sub("beta-catenin", "PROTEIN", s, 1)
print(s)
```

output:

```
alpha-catenin inhibits PROTEIN signaling by preventing formation of a beta-catenin*T-cell factor*DNA complex.
```

Answer (score -1):

I would have solved it the following way:

```
    line = 'alpha-catenin inhibits beta-catenin signaling by preventing             
    formation of a beta-catenin*T-cell factor*DNA complex.'

    new = (line.split('beta-catenin'))
    print(('PROTEIN').join(new))
```

this also ensures that each occurrence will be replaced.
if you need any further help please let me know.

Comment: Only the first occurrence is meant to be replaced. I think you've misunderstood the question

Comment: ok, then if only the first occurrence needs to be changed so the best is using replace:   str.replace(old, new,occurrence number)